# Why does (null+"").equals("null") return true in Java?

Tags: java, string, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenating null strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260723/concatenating-null-strings-in-java)

Why is obj equals "null"?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Object obj = null+"";
 System.out.println(obj.equals("null"));
}
```

java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)

Answer (score 3):

String.equals() compares the contents of the Strings.

The objects are both strings and contain the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(obj);
```

and then print:

```
System.out.println(obj.equals("null"));
```

Can you see it ... The content you saved is 'null' and you are matching content 'null'