# Java String concatenation - nulls

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenating null strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260723/concatenating-null-strings-in-java)

I'm just wondering if someone can explain why does the following code works the way it does:

```
String a = null;
String b = null;
String c = a + b;
System.out.println(c.toString());
```

This prints "nullnull" to the console.

I was kind of expecting that the operation + would thrown an exception or, to a lesser degree, that "c" would be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"String conversion," required by the concatenation operator, mandates that null values are to be mapped to the four characters `null` whenever a string representation is needed.

Spec for string conversion: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11

Spec for string concatenation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, perfect. I voted to close the question, since a duplicate was found otherwise yours would be the answer that I would accept

Answer (score 9):

because that code compiles to

```
String c = new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).toString();
```

and `StringBuilder.append(a)` appends the result of [`String.valueof(a)` which is `"null"` if `a` is `null`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: In this specific case, you are correct. However in the more general case of printing null strings: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29  & http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11

Comment: It is not correct, in my case it convert that line in `String c = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(a)).append(b).toString();`. The real reason is the `String.valueOf(Object)` implementation.

Comment: @dash1e it depends on implementation really besides `append(null)` also needs to append "null"

Comment: @ratchetfreak Not all the JDK convert the string concatenation to a StringBuilder expression.

Comment: The way the compiler transform the concatenation expression is not the reason of the result. Every compiler can achieve that result as prefer. The right answer is the @Joni Salonen answer.

Answer (score 0):

When java find a `null` reference during the string concatenation convert it to the string `"null"`. So `"nullnull"` is the right result.

Before concatenation for every object Java call

```
java.lang.String.valueOf(Object)
```

and if you look at the source code of that method you find this

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
  return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```