# Strange output in String in Java

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenating null strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260723/concatenating-null-strings-in-java)

Please find below the code snippet

```
String str = null;
str = str + "hi";

System.out.println(str)
```

The output of the above code is `nullhi`.

I thought the output will be `hi`, so kind of surprised with the output and not able to find the reason behind it.

Can someone please explain it.

Comment: It took me just 5 seconds to get that link of the post. Please use Google on regular basis.

Comment: i wasn't sure about the text to be used for google search, so directly posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From JLS.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html

**§15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +** ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1))

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run-time.

**§5.1.11. String Conversion** ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11))

> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).

Answer (score 4):

This is because `append` method. `+` gets converted as either `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` append operations.

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
if (str == null) str = "null";

public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Below is the generated byte code for your program

```
 0  aconst_null
 1  astore_1 [str]
 2  new java.lang.StringBuilder [16]
 5  dup
 6  aload_1 [str]
 7  invokestatic java.lang.String.valueOf(java.lang.Object) : java.lang.String [18]
10  invokespecial java.lang.StringBuilder(java.lang.String) [24]
13  ldc <String "hi"> [27]
15  invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.append(java.lang.String) : java.lang.StringBuilder [29]
18  invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.toString() : java.lang.String [33]
21  astore_1 [str]
22  getstatic java.lang.System.out : java.io.PrintStream [37]
25  aload_1 [str]
26  invokevirtual java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) : void [43]
29  return
```

So your code actully gets transformed into `append(null)` and then `append("hi")` which is why you get such output

Also it is clearly documented in [`15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

> An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate String object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.

Comment: These are good and fun facts, but the true reason for OP's observation  lies not with compiler implementation details, but with the JLS that clearly specifies the semantics of the concatenation operator.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Your comments always add to my knowledge. Added such reference from `JLS`

Answer (score 1):

`null` is the value printed if you try to print a null reference in java.

Answer (score 1):

When you concatenate values together that are not all strings, those that are not are converted as if by `String.valueOf`.  `String.valueOf(null)` is the string `"null"`.

Comment: But `str` **is a String**, so this doesn't explain it.

Comment: `null` is not a String (indeed it is not any object).

Comment: Do you mean to imply that the compiler makes code that **dynamically checks** whether to use `String.valueOf`? Your implication is false: `String.valueOf` **is always called** for all reference-typed arguments to `+`.

Comment: Fair point, I was trying to describe the effect, not the mechanism.

Comment: The description of effect is also simpler if you just say "all operands are transformed as if by `String.valueOf`."

Answer (score 0):

That was a decision that the creators of Java made early on. Any null value that is concatenated to a string will be output as `null`. This sort of makes sense if you imagine that you are trying to output a log message:

```
String personName = null;
System.out.println("Person name is: " + personName);
```

Result:

> Person name is: null

That behavior can help you when debugging because you know that the variable was actually null (as opposed to an empty string, e.g.).

They could have chosen to simply throw an exception when you tried to do this, but that would have caused a lot of things to break even when doing something like building a log message or exception string.

They could also have done as you expected and made null values get output as an empty string. This is what the .NET framework does. But ultimately, that's not what they decided to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the example shown by you 
you are concatenating the string null with hi so the output generated is
    **nullhi**

```
String str = null;
str = str + "hi";

System.out.println(str);


as str=str+"hi "//shows one string is concatenating with the other
```

so the output you get is right.