# Null values of Strings and Integers in Java

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, addition, autoboxing

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = null;
        String s1 = null;
        Integer i = null;
        Integer i1 = null;

        System.out.println(s+i);
        System.out.println(i+s);
        System.out.println(s+s1);

        try {
            System.out.println(i+i1);
        } catch (NullPointerException np) {         
            System.out.print("NullPointerException");       
        }
    }

}
```

The question is simple - why do I receive a `NullPointerException` only at the last line?

Comment: null string concatenation in java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260723/concatenating-null-strings-in-java

Comment: plus 1 for such a nice observational question

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your code makes use of two different [additive operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18). The first three lines use [string concatenation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1), whereas the last one uses [numeric addition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2).

String concatenation is [well-defined to turn `null` into `"null"`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> - If the reference is `null`, it is converted to the string `"null"` (four ASCII characters `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`).

Hence there is no NPE.

Adding two `Integer` objects together requires them to be [unboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8). This results in the `null` reference being dereferenced, which leads to the NPE:

> - If `r` is null, unboxing conversion throws a `NullPointerException`

Comment: +1 for quoting JLS rather then diving into implementation details (see my answer ;-)).

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: I felt obliged to chime in on a question about NPE. :)

Comment: @NPE Why does adding two Integer objects requires them to be unboxed ?

Comment: @Geek: Because the JLS says so: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2

Answer (score 17):

Notice that first three `+` operator usages involve string concatenation. Only the last one is the actual numeric *sum*. When string concatenation is involved (where `s` variable is involved), Java compiler uses some clever trick to improve performance. It replaces `+` operator with `StringBuilder`. For example your first line is translated to:

```
StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
tmp.append(s);
tmp.append(i);
System.out.println(tmp);
```

`StringBuilder` is `null`-friendly so no matter what you pass as an argument, it nicely replaces it with `"null"` string.

The situation is different in the last line. There you reference two `Integer` objects. The only that the JVM can do here is to unbox them (`i.intValue()`) and do the actual computation. Unboxing of `null` causes `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 5):

The concatenation (`+` operator) of anything with a `String` results in a `String`. Every operand is first converted to a String (either using `toString()`, or using the value `"null"`), then concatenated.

But the last operation involves `Integer`s only, so the previous rules don't apply. Instead of a concatenation, it does an addition. But to add two `Integer`s, it converts objects (`Integer`s) to primitive values (int), which is not possible if the `Integer` is null. That's why you get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: 1. *Every operand is first converted to a String* - nope, `null.toString()` still throws. 2. `System.out.println()` accepts `Object` and handles `null` fine, no `toString()` is really needed.

Comment: I didn't say that `toString()` was applied, but that null values are converted to a String containing "null". Perhaps I was not clear enough, I agree :) Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a case of auto-unboxing.  If you've got two `Integer`s `first` and `second`, then the result of their addition will be `first.intValue() + second.intValue()`.  Since both of them are null, that results in an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the bytecode for you program. You will notice that your null object is being passed as a parameter to the PrintStream.print() method. The source code for the print() method uses String.valueOf() as shown below:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that the answer to this question should have been obvious from the output:

```
C:\Temp>java Test
nullnull
nullnull
nullnull
NullPointerException
```