# Concatenating to null variable produces unexpected result in Java

Tags: java, string, null

This program

```
public class OddBehavior {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] words = new String[3];
        words[0] += "ify";
        System.out.println(words[0]);
    }
}
```

has the following output:

[image]

I initialized an array of 3 `String`s, which I thought would be `null`. But by adding the string "ify" to the end of `words[0]`, the `words[0]` got the value `"nullify"`, i.e. it already contained the String `"null"` (the `String`, not the value `null`!)

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260723/concatenating-null-strings-in-java/4260803#4260803).

Comment: There's no one good answer.  If the Java gods had declared "a `null` value string shall print as empty-string", then someone right about now would be posting to SO asking if it wouldn't have been better to print "null" instead.  It's simply a decision that was made, no better or worse than another decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code `words[0] += "ify"` is equivalent to `words[0] = words[0] + "ify"`.  When Strings are concatenated with the `+` operator, Java internally uses a `StringBuilder` to put them together.  When `null` is appended to a StringBuilder, it uses the literal `"null"` instead. That is why this happens.