# How come you can print: "true" + null but not: true + null?

Tags: java, null

The following compiles:

```
System.out.println("true" + null);
```

which I assume is because the existence of a string, converts "null" to a string as well.

However, since this works:

```
System.out.println(true);
```

It would seem that the following would also compile, since apparently "true" functions as a string.

```
System.out.println(true + null);
```

However, it doesn't compile.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: `"true" + null` results in `String` concatenation. The result is well defined, it is a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator works for numbers (`int`, `float`, `double`) and `String`s, but in this case you're using it to *add* a `boolean` and an `Object` (which is `null`), which is wrong.

> However,  since this works
>
> ```
> System.out.println(true);
> ```
>
> It would seem that the following would also compile, since apparently "true" functions as a string.
>
> System.out.println(true + null);

The former works since `System.out.println(boolean)` will convert the `boolean` into a `String`. The latter won't.

---

Doing some research about why `null` converts to `"null"` without generating any problem, since:

- `null.toString()` doesn't compile for obvious reasons
- `StringBuilder.append(null)` doesn't compile
- `String.valueOf(null)` compiles but throws a `NullPointerException` at runtime

Looks like the compiler instead taking `null` directly, it will first create an `Object o` and then  `String s` variable and assign `null` to it, then use `String.valueOf(s)`. So, this code:

```
System.out.println("true" + null);
```

Is in fact

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("true").append((Object)null).toString());
```

If we do the inverse:

```
 System.out.println(null + "true");
```

This will become:

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append((Object)null).append("true").toString());
```

To show that this is nor magic nor black sorcery, I just wrote a simple code to replicate the situation:

```
public class TestNullString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        nullPlusString();
        stringPlusNull();
    }
    public static void nullPlusString() {
        System.out.println(null + "foo");
    }
    public static void stringPlusNull() {
        System.out.println("foo" + null);
    }
}
```

Compile the class using `java TestNullString.java`, then decompiling it using `javap -c TestNullString.class`, which generated (comments auto generated by decompiler itself, not mine):

```
Compiled from "TestNullString.java"
public class TestNullString {
  public TestNullString();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method nullPlusString:()V
       3: invokestatic  #3                  // Method stringPlusNull:()V
       6: return        

  public static void nullPlusString();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: new           #5                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       6: dup           
       7: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      10: aconst_null   
      11: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      14: ldc           #8                  // String foo
      16: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      19: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      22: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      25: return        

  public static void stringPlusNull();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: new           #5                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       6: dup           
       7: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      10: ldc           #8                  // String foo
      12: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      15: aconst_null   
      16: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      19: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      22: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      25: return        
}
```

By going to the implementation of `StringBuilder#append(Object)`, it shows:

```
public StringBuilder append(Object obj) {
    return append(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

And `String#valueOf(Object)` implementation:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Which completely shows why `null` becomes, in the end, `"null"`.

Another effort to explain this was done here: [Concatenating null strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4260723/1065197)

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but to explain why null prints as "null", why post bytecode when it is written in the docs.

Comment: @PeterMmm I was just curious how this is done *behind the scenes* because the compiler is responsible for this to happen, but as we know, this isn't done magically.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't compile because the statement operands `true` and `null` are not applicable for the `+` operation. The applicable couples are:

- all numeric types, including wrappers. For example: `new Integer(1) + new Integer(2)`
- String + Object (because the `.toString()` method is defined for every object). For example: `"newObject().toString() + "cde"`.
- String + null. For example: `"abc" + null`

Notes (thanks to @Luiggi and @Sotirios):

- The result `String.valueOf(null)` won't work as a possible operand as it will throw a `NullPointerException` ...
- ...but `String.valueOf((Object) null)` will return the `String` value `"null"`

Comment: + is aplicabel to every object because toString() is defined in java.lang.Object.

Comment: `null` cannot execute `toString`.

Comment: Note that `String.valueOf(null)` will throw `NullPointerException`, but `String.valueOf((Object)null)` will return the `String` value `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
since apparently "true" functions as a string.
```

This assumption is wrong. It works because you call

```
public void println(boolean x)
```

However,

```
true + null
```

is not a valid statement in Java, as you cannot add nor append boolean and Object.

Answer (score 1):

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18)

> If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the
>   operation is string concatenation.

and concatenation is made by [StringBuilder.append()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Please put a reference for what happens with `null`.

Comment: That is written in the Javadocs, follow them to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Edit it into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The statement *between* the parens are executed before it is ever printed. The problem is not string conversion, the problem is, as others have stated, is that

```
true + null
```

is an addition problem that makes no sense.

```
"true" + null
```

however, is *not* addition--it's string concatenation. Since "true" is a string, the meaning of the `+` is changed from "addition" to "concatenation".

Answer (score 0):

In case of

```
System.out.println(true + null);
```

it tries to convert null to `boolean` and because boolean has  only `false` and `true` values it can not cast and doesn't compile.

In case of

```
System.out.println("true" + null);
```

`null` casted to String because `String` can has `null` value (String is a `Object`)

Comment: "it tries to convert null to boolean and because boolean has only false and true values it can not cast and doesn't compile." - and if it did convert null to boolean, what would the `+` do? `true + false` doesn't make any sense.