# Skipping one value when storing into an array

Tags: java, arrays, class

Can someone help me check ?

**error**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How do I remove this error ?

my main Class:

```
public class deck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck app = new Deck();
        app.Deck();
    }

}
```

my Deck class:

```
    public class Deck {
    public int TOTALCARDS;
    Card[] d;
    public int nH;


    public void createDeck() {
            String[] suitsArray = new String[4];

            for(int i=0; i<numArray.length; i++) {
                numArray[i] = i+1;
            }

            for (int i=0; i<13; i++) { 
                if (i!=11){
                deck[i+25] = new Card(suitsArray[2], i+1);
                }
                else if(i > 10){
                    deck[i+25] = new Card(suitsArray[2], i+1);
                }
                }
    for (int i=0; i<13; i++) {
        deck[i+25].display();
    }
}
```

This is the Card Class.

```
public class Card {

        public String suit;
        public int number;


        public Card(String s, int n){
            this.suit = s;
            this.number = n;
        }


        public String words;
        public String getTitle(){
            String 
            if (number == 1){
                words = " Ace";

            }
            else if (number ==3){
                words = " Three";
            }
            else if (number ==4){
                words = " Four";
            }
            else if (number ==5){
                words = " Five";
            }
            else if (number ==6){
                words = " Six";
            }
            else if (number ==7){
                words = " Seven";
            }
            else if (number ==8){
                words = " Eight";
            }
            else if (number ==9){
                words = " Nine";
            }
            else if (number ==10){
                words = " Ten";
            }
            else if (number ==11){
                words = " Jack";
            }
            else if (number ==12){
                words = " Queen";
            }
            else if (number ==13){
                words = " King";
            }
            displayTitle = suit + words;
                    if (displayTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Diamond Queen")){
                        displayTitle= "DIAMOND QUEEN";
                    }


        return (displayTitle);

    }

        public void display(){
            System.out.println("< " + get() + " >");
        }
    }
```

When I run the code I got

```
Hearts Ace
Hearts Two
Hearts Three
Hearts Four
Hearts Five
Hearts Six
Hearts Seven
Hearts Eight
Hearts Nine
Hearts Ten
Hearts Jack
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Deck.createDeck(Deck.java:57)
    at Deck.<init>(Deck.java:9)
    at deckMain.main(deckMain.java:5)
```

Comment: Can you give the exception traceback, it's super helpful. The traceback will give a line number... which would be great because I don't see room for a NullPointer in what you posted. Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Where/How do you declare `deck`? It seems you are leaving out relevant code.

Comment: There is simply not enough information here to tell where an NPE could be coming from.  A hunch of mine is that it's coming from within your `Card` constructor, but I can't be sure.  Nothing here would cause an NPE (provided `deck` is actually instantiated).

Comment: @Makoto I think Takendarkk is right to ask how op define deck array in its code. do not you agree?

Comment: @KickButtowski:  No doubt.  But until we get that, this question is completely unanswerable.

Comment: Is -3 completely necessary? OP seems new, that's for sure, but he did attempt to post his code and his issue (and kindly asked for an easier to understand answer since he's new). For a new user that's unimaginable.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Downvotes will probably continue to roll in the longer OP refuses to reply to requests for more info.

Comment: @Takendarkk He's probably doing it as we are downvoting him. Not a lot of time has passed since the request for more code was posted.

Comment: I am sorry for the unclear codes, as I am first time asking question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Plenty of time has passed. Also, this is why you can reverse a vote when a post is edited.

Comment: It seems to me like `words` is null at this point `String displayTitle = suit + words;` at the top of `getTitle()`. However, those code you posted doesn't show you calling any methods that would get there so hard to say.

Comment: @Takendarkk please refer to the code, I have insert  the output of the program.

Comment: The code you posted never calls any of the methods in your Card class, but your output indicates you are doing just that. Have you still left out relevant code?

Comment: @FrezzeyTsuna I kind of ran your code and did not get such error

Comment: You need to post the _exact_ code which produces this error, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: @FrezzeyTsuna can you post up your driver class too?

Comment: @Takendarkk I help put the neccessary code in already I am really sorry. I not in the good mind state, been trying to solve this for very long already.

Comment: @FrezzeyTsuna No worries. We keep asking because we want to help you. Everyone has been new and frustrated at some point.

Comment: When you see in the error `at Deck.createDeck(Deck.java:57)`, 57 is the line number of the code that gave the error. Knowing which line it is helps identify the problem.

Comment: @FrezzeyTsuna Don't just edit your answer to remove code, other people may experience the same problem and can learn from your question. If you don't want it to stay, press the delete option.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: See the comment by Kick Buttowski below, this is at best a partial answer.

---

You're calling `Card.display()`

```
for (int i=0; i<13; i++) {
    deck[i+25].display();
}
```

Which in turn calls `Card.getTitle()`

```
public void display(){
    System.out.println("< " + getTitle() + " >");
}
```

The problem lies there:

```
public String getTitle(){
    String displayTitle = suit + words; // <-- Problem
    if (number == 1){
        words = " Ace";
    }
    // ...
```

At the marked line, `words` is not set yet, so it's `null`. Accessing its value will raise a `NullPointerException`.

As Takendarkk pointed out, you can overcome this with minimal changes to your code by initialising it either in your constructor or in the declaration:

```
public class Card {
    // ...
    String words = "";
```

Or, since (as far as we know) `words` is only used within `display()`, move it there:

```
public void display() {
    String words = ""; // Still need to be initialised
    // ...
```

Comment: You can fix this by declaring `words` with empty string by default `public String words = "";`. I think you should add that to your answer.

Comment: I really doubt that is the answer. I never heard String throw nullpointerexception

Comment: @KickButtowski you're right, the `null` string won't be a problem if it's only concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Your card size is 51 ... it should be 52

```
if (i!=11){
    deck[i+25] = new Card(suitsArray[2], i+1);
}
else if(i > 11){
    deck[i+25] = new Card(suitsArray[2], i+1);
}
```

This doesn't add up, what if i = 11?? You do nothing as

```
i!=11 =  false and i > 11 == false;
```

this means the else if (i > 11) will never execute.
also your code does the exact same thing??

if you are trying to initalise all 52 cards you can do something like:

```
for (int i=0;i<deck.size;i++) {
   deck[i] = new Card(suitsArray[i/13], numArray[i % 13]);
```

EDIT: after more of an explanation of what you are doing .....

```
for (int i=0, j=0;j<deck.length;i++) {
    if ((i/13) == 2 && (i%13) == 11)
        continue;
    deck[j++] = new Card( suitsArray[i/13], (i % 13));
}
```

also in card have (much clearer)
`static String[] titles = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};`
and

```
public String getTitle() {

        return suit + " " + titles[number];

}
```

Comment: why the first snippet code of your post does not add up? can you explain please?

Comment: I am trying to leave out Queen of Heart. As my assignment told me to do so. I place the second part try to help to skip the value.

Comment: @FrezzeyTsuna can you please post up your driver class as well?

Comment: @FrezzeyTsuna did you post up compelete code for deck class here?

Comment: Which part of this answer addresses the NPE?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your value at deck[11] is null because you skipped putting an instance of Card at that index.

edit: `[should be deck[i + 25]]`, where `i = 11`;

Regarding the answers pointing to the variable word being null as reason of NPE. I doubt this. I have tried the code in my machine and it is not giving me NPE. (see also [Concatenating null strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260723/concatenating-null-strings-in-java))

Comment: Not really, although that's probably the intended behaviour. But the code is `if (i!=11) { ... } else if(i > 10) { ... }`. With i=11, the else branch is entered, and it does create a card in `deck[i+25]`.

Comment: hmmm... the original condition was if( i > 11). (see answer by KevH)

Comment: yes, looking through edits it looks like it changed a few times