# Why i'm getting a null string when i try to add the splitted string?

Tags: java, string, split

I have `splited` a string and from the recieved string i am trying to form a word everything is comming fine but everytime i get `null` string in the first `index` why?

Here is my code:

```
    String assetClasses = "Gold:Stocks:Fixed Income:Commodity:Interest Rates";
    String[] splits = assetClasses.toString().split(":");

    //System.out.println("splits.size: " + splits.length);
    String ab = null;
for(int i=0; i<splits.length;i++){
    System.out.println(splits[i]);
    ab+=splits[i];
}
System.out.println(ab);
```

The output:

`Gold`
`Stocks`
`Fixed`
`Income`
`Commodity`
`Interest Rates`

`nullGoldStocksFixed IncomeCommodityInterest Rates`

Comment: Why are you calling `toString()` on a String?

Comment: because i want the string to be unique code which is the date that i am talking dynamically to put it in sqlite db for some operation

Comment: Maybe it's null because you made it null?

Comment: ya thanks i got the answer

Comment: @Hell Calling `toString()` on a string doesn't make it unique, it just gives you back a reference to the string that you already had. It's effectively a wasted method call - just use the reference that you already have.

Comment: but adding up all the string gives an unique figure i hope you can see that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `String ab = null;` to `String ab = "";`

As a complement, see [Concatenating null strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260723/concatenating-null-strings-in-java) to know what's happening when you use `String ab = null;`

Comment: @Hell: As a minor note, although the above will work, when concatenating strings it is recommended you use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: ohh thanks this works for me and i just need the datestring to be one to place it as unique id in my database

Answer (score 1):

It gives null because in java's String class below is the implementation of valueOf api of String class.

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also - String is immutable, so you're creating lot's of unnecessary objects during this method execution. Use mutable StringBuilder instead:

```
    String assetClasses = "Gold:Stocks:Fixed Income:Commodity:Interest Rates";
    String[] splits = assetClasses.split(":");

    StringBuilder ab = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(splits[i]);
        ab.append(splits[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(ab.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me stress on what [npinti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243943/npinti) said. Strings are immutable in java. Which means every time you say `ab+=splits[i];` you are creating a new string. Which is a really slow and inefficient process.

Instead, you can;

```
String assetClasses = "Gold:Stocks:Fixed Income:Commodity:Interest Rates";
String[] splits = assetClasses.toString().split(":");

//System.out.println("splits.size: " + splits.length);
StringBuilder ab = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<splits.length;i++){
    System.out.println(splits[i]);
    ab.append(splits[i]);
}
System.out.println(ab.toString());
```

Its that simple!