# why does the string concatenation operator write null for null and "" for '\0000'"?

Tags: java

I am comparing the following two lines of code and their output:

`System.out.print("x = "+'\u0000');`

> output:  `x =`

`System.out.print("x = "+null);`

> output: `x = null`

We know that in unicode system `'\u0000'` is `null` so how does it print as the string `""`, while `null` is printed as `"null"`?

Comment: @kocko, this is potentially a bad choice of duplicate. The actual duplicate is more likely to be [Concatenating null strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260723/concatenating-null-strings-in-java) as the question here is "why does the string concatenation operator write `null` for null and `""` for `'\0000'`"?

Comment: @Andy Brown - thanks

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not a character. You can use it for object references without a value.
`\u0000` is a literal for `new Character(0)`. It *is* an instance of a class, while `null` is not.

So the `toString()` Method of a Character instance returns the character as it should be displayed. `null` doesn't have a `toString()`, `String.valueOf(null)` is called instead which returns `"null"`.

Comment: While valid, this doesn't answer the original question about why `System.out.print("x = "+null);` prints `x = null`, and `System.out.print("x = "+'\u0000');` prints `x = `