# Stringification of null in Java

Tags: java

Consider

```
public String toString()
{
    return foo + bar;
}
```

where `foo` and `bar` are both fields of the class.

If `foo` and `bar` are either or both null, does the JLS guarantee that the string `(null)` is returned for each field, or does it reserve the right to throw an NPE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260723/concatenating-null-strings-in-java

Comment: With respect the dupe is adding an explicit non-null string to a null. So maybe then '+' is already in "string concatenation" mode. Mine can add a null to another null.

Comment: try adding 2 null's  together, according to the answers in the other question, it works

Comment: @P45Imminent The JLS (as quoted in the duplicate) says that each operand will be converted to "null" if it is null,

Comment: Excellent. I have a nice answer below. Thank you all very much.

Comment: @P45Imminent Cracking username. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11:

> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).

So yes, it will not throw a NPE (as long as the `+` resolves to a string concatentation, rather than an arithmetic operation)

**EDIT**:

Actually, looking at this carefully, the behaviour isn't technically defined.

String conversion only applies to an argument to `+` that is not a string. If both arguments are a string, then no conversion is done (so 5.1.11 does not apply).

We then move onto http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1, which only specifies the following:

> ...The characters of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand operand in the newly created string.

Note there's no reference to `null`s.

So I don't think the behaviour of `(String)null + (String)null` is technically defined...

Comment: Hum. That's even more interesting following your edit. I guess the pragmatic thing to do is to prefix the expression with `""`.

Comment: `null` is of the null type, not of the String type - so string conversion is applied...

Comment: @P45Imminent it's a safe bet that it will work as you expect, it's merely a hole in the spec. Any half-decent java compiler will deal with this correctly.

Answer (score -2):

It does not throw any error.
It tries to convert both the arguments to string if they are not already strings.
String representation of null is "null"
Hence, here is the output:

foo ------- bar  ------ foo+bar

null ------ null ------"nullnull"

null ------"str" ------"nullstr"

"str" -----null  -------"strnull"

Comment: Can someone let me know why my answer is being downvoted? I tried a sample and those are the outputs it gives exactly. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The fact that you observe this behaviour doesn't at all address any guarantees the JLS might give.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. The fact that null is converted to "null" is from JLS only. Anyways thanks. I will try to be specific.