# How to assign a null reference to a String in Java

Tags: java, string, null

Below code tests if the Strings myStr and newStr contain the same values. I expected the result to be equal, but to my surprise the line `String newStr = null` seems to result in newStr taking in 'null' as actual text. Is this correct?

I expected it just to be assigned a reference to nothing, resulting in no value at that point.

```
String myStr = "java";
char[] myCharArr = {'j', 'a', 'v', 'a'};
String newStr = null; // not an empty reference but assigning the text "null"?
for (char value : myCharArr) {
   newStr = newStr + value;
}
System.out.println(newStr == myStr); // results in false: newStr is 'nulljava' and myStr 'java'
```

Note that when changing `"String newStr = null"` to `String newStr = new String()` you do get an empty reference and newStr will end up just being "java".

Comment: First you should check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260723/concatenating-null-strings-in-java
And second, you should use equals method to get the correct result of comparison of two string. 
Please check this link for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java

Comment: What do you expect `newStr + value` to evaluate to at the very first iteration of the loop, while your `newStr` is still `null`? I.e. what do you expect `null + 'j'` to be?

Comment: `String newStr = null;`  will result in `newStr` having the value `null` (or more precisely it references nothing). However, in string concatenation Java has special handling for `null`, i.e. it turns it into `"null"` and that's why `newStr + "java"` results in `"nulljava"`. Initialize `newStr` to an empty string instead, e.g. `newStr = ""`.

Comment: It is "taking the value", only because you concatenate/print the "null-string" ...the (only) alternative would be an exception, right!? ...sorry that it doesn't behave as "empty string" (as you expect)

Comment: Okay so null is converted to "null" when you print the string or add some other value to it. And when you use a concat on it.. you would except it to concat to "null", but instead this time it will throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 5):

When performing

```java
newStr = newStr + value;
```

The `null` in `newStr` is converted to a string, being `"null"`. Another thing you should keep in mind is that `==` compares references, and to compare `String`s themselves, you should use `str1.equals(str2)` instead.